# Knockout toJson with multiple view models

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I have a simple Knockout setup in which I'm attempting to implement multiple view models. It appears to work with one problem: proper use of toJSON eludes me.

My html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Playground</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="content/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="appHost">
<section id="nameHeader">
    <label>
    First Name:
    <input data-bind="value: firstName, enable: canEdit" />
    </label>
    <button data-bind="click: toggleEdit" class="btn btn-primary">Toggle Edit</button>
</section>
<section id="other">
    <label>
    First Name:
    <input data-bind="value: firstName, enable: canEdit" />
    </label>

    <button data-bind="click: toggleEdit" class="btn btn-primary">Toggle Edit</button>

</section>

<h2>Debugging View</h2>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON({name1: self.NameViewModel, name2: self.OtherViewModel})"></pre>

<script type="text/javascript" src="sample.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My sample.js is:

```
(function (app, $, ko) {
    var self = this;

    var NameViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.firstName = ko.observable('');
    self.canEdit = ko.observable(true);

    self.toggleEdit = function () {
        self.canEdit(!self.canEdit());
    };

    };

    var OtherViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.firstName = ko.observable('');
    self.canEdit = ko.observable(true);

    self.toggleEdit = function () {
        self.canEdit(!self.canEdit());
    };

    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
    //ko.applyBindings(new NameViewModel());
    ko.applyBindings(new NameViewModel(), $("#nameHeader")[0]);
    ko.applyBindings(new OtherViewModel(), $("#other")[0]);
    });

})(window.app = window.app || {}, jQuery, ko);
```

If I refactor so that there is only one view model, and change toJSON to use $root, the page works as expected . . . that is to say, I see a JSON view of my model in the "Debugging" section of the HTML.

How do I get a view-model-specific view using toJSON? Or, how can I get the entire page as a single JSON object . . . that possible? I have tried:

ko.toJSON(NameViewModel)

and the code in my example above is my most recent attempt to see both models.

Any help is appreciated.

Vic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

```
ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)
```

should accomplish what you are looking for

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. The line, after the change, is:<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data , null, 2)"></pre>. No change.

Comment: put it at the top of the page, right above your top section element.
if you could put your code in a jsfiddle to show the issue, this would be easier to help with.

Comment: I misread your code: look at this http://jsfiddle.net/wj4sLs0y/7/
You are outside of the context of those bindings when you are calling it where you are. That data is valid to the element you have bound it to.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So, when implementing multiple view models, is there a way to see the entire page as a single JSON, or is that nonsense?

Comment: The way I would do this is one view per view model. You could have that view have multiple objects in it, but I would create one viewmodel for the whole page.